# Like Button-Redirecting to a separate page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have this facebook application developed.Towards the start of my application I have added a like button so that the user will hit like.I want to customize it such a way that the user will be redirected to the application if and only if he/she hits the like button.Can somebody please help me implement this?The snippet code i implement for the like button is:

Can I use  FB.event.subscribe to implement the above function?

Thanks in advance!!!:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use `FB.event.subscribe` to achieve that using

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response); 
     // In your case 
     window.location = 'YOUR_URL'
    }
);
```

[Demo (with Alert)](http://jsfiddle.net/fx5JQ/)

[Demo (redirecting to Facebook page)](http://jsfiddle.net/fx5JQ/2/show/)